# Bitmap resources depending on screen densities

Tags: android, resources, screen

The Android documentation being the mess that it is, I have big problem understanding what sizes my icons should be for each of the densities. The ultra-lengthy article( http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html ) on supporting multiple-screen doesn't provide the information.

So I was going to just guess some sizes when I finally hit that this gem in the "providing ressources" article ( http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources ) :

> There is thus a 3:4:6 scaling ratio
>   between the three densities, so a 9x9
>   bitmap in ldpi is 12x12 in mdpi and
>   18x18 in hdpi.

Thing is they just introduced the xhdpi density.

So now what is the x in 3:4:6:x ??

**EDIT :** Added link as asked by commenter

Comment: Might help to provide links or info on where in the documentation you found that that info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's in the page you linked to, but somewhat hidden in Table 1:

- ldpi: 120 dpi
- mdpi: 160 dpi
- hdpi: 240 dpi
- xhdpi: 320 dpi

So it's 3:4:6:8.

Comment: Thanks, I must have missed it. I'm all set now ... Photoshop and goooooo :D